# Indices Question | Find the value of n.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, formal-power-series

I am having trouble working out this question and I wanted to know if someone could explain how to work it out.

> Given that $$81^{-\frac34} = 3^n.$$ Find the value of n.

This is what I have done so far and I don't know where to go from here.

$81^{-\frac34} = (9^2)^{-\frac34} = 9^{2\times -\frac34}$

Thanks.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: since $$3^4=81$$ we have $$(3^4)^{-3/4}=3^{-3}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$3^{4\cdot\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)}=3^n$$ or
$$3^{-3}=3^n$$ or
$$n=-3$$